# Integrating Flood with Tricentis Neoload

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, neoload, flood-element

Im wondering if it is possible to integrate flood with Tricentis Neoload?

I've tried searching on the internet but with no valid result of integrating both of them together.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your Jmeter scripts directly in Neoload